# UNION doesn't return all rows

Tags: mysql, union

My head is about to explode.. For some reason mysql doesn't want to return all rows from a UNION statement.

If I use

```
SELECT `full_address` FROM `x_servers` WHERE `service_type` IN ('boost','testboost')
```

It returns 51 rows, while if I use

```
(SELECT `full_address` FROM `x_servers` WHERE `service_type` = 'boost') UNION (SELECT `full_address` FROM `x_servers` WHERE `service_type` = 'testboost')
```

It gives 25.

When I use them seperately,

```
SELECT `full_address` FROM `x_servers` WHERE `service_type` = 'boost'
```

returns 31 rows and

```
SELECT `full_address` FROM `x_servers` WHERE `service_type` = 'testboost'
```

returns 20

What is a possible problem? I cannot see it.

Server: MySQL (Localhost via UNIX socket)
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 - (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

IIRC SQL's `UNION` removes duplicates. So when using it with rows that have same `full_address` only one of the duplicates will show up in the final output.
But with a normal SQL `SELECT` duplicates won't be removed (Unless you use `DISTINCT`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however if I use SELECT DISTINCT `full_address` FROM `x_servers` WHERE `service_type` = 'boost', it returns 31 rows. And the UNION statement returns 25. So it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: How about `SELECT DISTINCT full_address FROM x_servers WHERE service_type IN ('boost','testboost')`?

Comment: It shows 49 rows

Comment: My bad. Was a phpmyadmin issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently that was a phpMyAdmin issue. For some reason all it showed was:  Showing rows 0 - 24 (25 total, Query took 0.0011 seconds.) And there were no other pages to go to. It normally shows other pages if they don't fit within the 25 rows limit but it didn't this time. It also did not show that there's more that 25 rows in total as it said "25 total". But once I pressed "show all" it showed the rest of the query.